# Why there is difference between IE generated DOM and CSQuery DOM?

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, csquery

I am trying to paras DOM of a site using CSQuery. If I open a site in IE and inspect an element, its HTML slightly differs ( ordering of attributes and spacing between values ) from same site loaded using CSQuery.CreateFromUrl method. For example there is a div style generated by IE as "style=margin-bottom: 0.5em;" and for same div CSQuery's Render method generated different HTML  "style=margin-bottom:0.5em;" [ No space after :].

As a result when I create a selector for CSQuery like "div[style='margin-left: 0.5em;']" it doesn't work because CSQuery's internal DOM doesn't have space between ':' and '0.5'.

My problem is my application users will be using IE to inspect DOM elements and hence creating CSS selectors to query DOM using CSQuery. For this case I can remove spaces from selector in my code but I dont want to do this because there might be some other slight differences between other selectors.

So is there any way to make sure CSQuery generate the same DOM as IE does ? 
I have tried using CSQuery.Creat( HTML return by IE ) but somehow CSQuery still format the HTML in its way which is different from IE DOM.

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

1. To ensure that you will get the same response in CsQuery object as in your IE browser to should turn off javascript in your browser and do not accept cookies from web site. (CQ.CreateFromURL returns a rendered DOM that did not been used by javascript). Also, sometimes there is a deferent in response connected by cookies.

In your case you just need to set a 'parse method'.

[Check out official documentation](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/documentation/create.md)

Look for a section 'Creating from HTML'.

Good luck.

Comment: I have tried different combinations of HtmlParsingMode & HtmlParsingOptions in create method but no use. And whats about sites which uses Ajax to load extra content , how CSQuery.CreatFromUrl handles such sites and generate DOM for them ?

Comment: Even if I get html from my webbrowser control and then create CSQuery object from this html, it changes/modify the formatting of html slightly...

Comment: @TonyMull if a web site loads something via AJAX, CsQuery will not handle that.In that case you need to find out a url and load it by your self.

Make a test: 
Run your URL on VS browser and see what response it returns. If it is the same that you got at your browser so the problem in CsQuery, but if it is not...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is neither IE or CsQuery, both are working as designed. The problem is that you are expecting the same output from two different parsing engines. IE uses mshtml from the best of my knowledge and CsQuery is emulating Gecko which Firefox uses. So to get the same output you would need to either switch to mshtml or get your users to use firefox. The combo you picked will have multiple differences because the parsing philosophy is slightly different and it shows in these anomalies you are seeing.